# How to set a input text (with no ID or name) value with a subsequent submit of that input text?

Tags: javascript

I have been trying already all kind of code snippets in Chrome Dev tools on this website:

http://kiwisdr.sk3w.se:8073/?#

This is a software defined radio running on a webserver. 
I would like to use Javascript to set the frequency (and submit) so that I can change the frequency the receiver is currently tuned to.

Manually on the GUI the user can just type a frequency (with or without enter) and the new frequeny inside the input box will be tuned.

This is the HTLM part of the website containing the input (no ID or name, so I am not sure how to properly adress this):

```html
<form id="id-freq-form" name="form_freq" action="#" onsubmit="freqset_complete(0); return false;">
  <input class="id-freq-input w3-input w3-border w3-hover-shadow" style="padding:0 4px;max-width:74px" size="8" onkeydown="freq_keydown(event)" onkeyup="freqset_keyup(this, event)" type="text" value="" onchange="w3_input_change('undefined', 'undefined')">
</form>
```

I managed to set the frequency, but I am stuck on how to make it submit.

This is the code I used to set the frequency input box to a certain value (1234.50):

```js
targetForm = document.forms['form_freq'];
targetForm.elements[0].value = '1234.50';
```

I already tried to trigger the keydown, keyup or change events using some snippets I found, but I am not sure I adress the right elements in the form with it.

All I want to do is to mimic a user entry by code :-)

Could someone point me into the right direction by having a look on the way how the input works on this website and how I can make the website update the currently received frequency with javascript?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer:

`freqset_keyup(document.forms[1][0], null)`

Nicer answer:

```
function change_freq(new_freq) {
  var form = document.forms['form_freq'];
  var freq_input = form.elements[0];
  freq_input.value = new_freq;
  freqset_keyup(freq_input, null);
}

change_freq(1234.50)
```

Comment: And thanks for your question. That's a really interesting web tool :)